# Primary Tile Title for windows phone app Market Place

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

For creating **primary cyclic tile** in application, do we must need to provide 'Title'.**Shall we use Tile Title as empty**? 
Note:We have done the image with application title.

2.In Primary Cyclic tile template we **couldn't find Medium size image tab to assign image**. Is application itself will assign the large image as medium image ? 
Note:We assigned Large image(691X336)png image and Small size image(159X159).

Please clarify me on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a "Tile Title" is entirely optional. If your image includes the name of your application or other content which would be duplicated in the title then this is a great reason not to include a title. This applies to all tile types, not just cyclic ones.

With the cyclic tile template you just provide the images and the OS will resize or clip the images, as appropriate, for each size of tile.